# Common kernel for compositions of epis?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

The following proposition is an excerpt from Osborne's *Basic Homological Algebra:
[image]

Regarding the proof: Why does there exist an arrow $j$ which is simultaneously the kernel of both $\pi$ and $\varphi \pi$? Can't there be an arrow $h$ with $\varphi \pi h=0$ yet $\pi h \neq 0$?

Comment: If I'm reading the proposition correctly, the existence of $j$ is assumed.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yep, you're right. It was late at night, sorry about the silly question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that in category theory a kernel of $f\colon A \to B$ is not an object $K \subseteq A$ but a map $K \to A$.  So the hypothesis that $\pi$ and $\varphi\pi$ have the same kernel means exactly that such a $j$ exists.

If the arrow you're asking about existed then this would be a map that $\ker\varphi\pi$ factored through but $\ker\pi$ didn't, so they certainly wouldn't be the same.